What is a better way to write this js script? Trying to format text in the Sentence way
I'm trying to build a convert case website using React.
Is there a better way to do this? Its supposed to remove extra spaces and capitalize the first letter after every '.'.
const handleSentanceFormat = () => {
    let line = text.split('\n');
    for(let i = 0; i < line.length; i++){
      let sentance = line[i].replace(/\s{1,}/g, ' ').replaceAll(' .', '.').trim().split(".");
      for(let j = 0; j < sentance.length; j++){
        let s = sentance[j].trim();
        sentance[j] = s.length === 0 ? '' : s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
      }
      line[i] = sentance.join(". ");
    }
    setText(line.join("\n"));
  };

Example:
Input:
abcd                        abcd.         aaaa.
aa         aa              .  aaa.

Output:
Abcd abcd. Aaaa.
Aa aa. Aaa.


For replacing contiguous spaces you can just do this (note you may want to consider tabs, and consecutive newlines which this does not).
text.replaceAll(/ +/g, " ");

For capitalisation:
text.replaceAll(/\.\s*./g, m => m.toUpperCase());


Actually that doesn't quite handle the very first letter but that's a pretty trivial change. Exercise for the reader.

text.replaceAll(/(^|\.)\s*./g, m => m.toUpperCase()); should handle the first letter too.
